# React span not refreshing after class change

Tags: reactjs

I have the following line:

**CSS:**

```
.hide_notice{
  visibility: hidden !important;
}

.show_notice{
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

**Code:**

```
<span className={this.state.post_msg.notice_class}>
   {this.state.post_msg.msg}
</span>
```

The default value is and empty message string and a notice_class of 'hide_notice'.

After an AJAX post, I'm changing the message to show the result, and changing the notice_class to show_notice . When I inspect the elements I see the class on the span changed successfully and the notice message was also inserted successfully, but the span isn't showing, I used the exact same thing in other parts of my app and they work fine, am I missing something here? I've also tried this with a Div, same result.

**EDIT:**

This is the code from inspection, the message is added in an internal span for some reason, but it also inherits show_notice:

```
<span class="show_notice" data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.3.0.0.0">
  <span data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.3.0.0.0.0">Save Completed</span>
</span>
```

Comment: If you inspect the element and see `visibile !important` on the span, but you still don't see it, then it's no longer a React issue, and perhaps a parent container is not visible.

Comment: The parent has other elements which are showing, so it has to be visible.

Comment: @Mankind1023 that extra span is because you are using a react version older than 0.15, it's currently fixed, https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html